# If an MEP resigns is the next person on the list appointed?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union

What is the process in the UK for when an MEP resigns?

Is the next person on the party’s list appointed?

In Northern Ireland they use Single Transferrable Vote - perhaps they pick the first loser?

Answer (score 2):

The process is [specific to each EU member state](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/news/en/faq/7/how-is-an-meps-who-resigns-replaced).

For the UK, in theory the next person on the Party's list gets appointed as explained in [this blog post](https://jonworth.eu/tories-breaking-law-replace-meps-leaving-european-parliament/), which adds references to the legal texts. Note that the latter is titled "Tories breaking the law on how they replace MEPs leaving the European Parliament?" - it details some of the machinations on what actually happens in practice.

Regarding NI specifically, I'm not familiar with the specifics but as a guess I'd expect that STV is used to work out which parties gets seats. That is, I'd expect they'd redistribute the votes of parties that don't meet the minimum vote threshold, and continue eliminating worst performers one by one until the 3 seats can unequivocally get attributed (to parties, rather than individuals) using the [d'Hondt method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Hondt_method).